# Correlacionando vetores através dos índices em Python

Tags: array, python-2.7

Possuo os seguintes vetores:

```
posicao_1 = [4, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 6, 8, 12, 17]

posicao_2 = [43, 61, 21, 19, 46, 63, 68, 72, 66, 89, 29, 10, 8, 7, 6, 15]
```

Preciso procurar no vetor POSICAO_1 o valor [24, 18].

```
posicao_1 = [4, 62, **24, 18**, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, **24, 18**, 6, 8, 12, 17]
```

Podemos observar que os mesmos se encontram nos índices [2, 3] e [10, 11] do vetor POSIÇÃO_1.

Após localizar esses valores, preciso percorrer o vetor POSIÇÃO_2 e atribuir valores aleatórios e IGUAIS nos ÍNDICES  [2, 3] e [10, 11] que localizei no vetor POSIÇÃO_1. Por exemplo:

Teria que atribuir valores aleatórios e IGUAIS:

```
posicao_2 = [43, 61, **21, 21**, 46, 63, 68, 72, 66, 89, **21, 21**, 8, 7, 6, 15]
```

Alguém, por gentileza, poderia me ajudar?

Desculpa, caso não tenha sido muito claro, tentei explicar o máximo possível!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do código da tua última pergunta precisas apenas de criar uma lista de indices e guardar os elementos onde esse código esta a colocar os aleatórios. Depois utiliza-la para substituir no segundo vetor `posicao_2`

Assim:

```
import random
aleatorio = random.randrange(0,200)

posicao_1 = [4, 62, 24, 18, 47, 62, 63, 78, 68, 87, 24, 18, 6, 8, 12, 17]
posicao_2 = [43, 61, 21, 19, 46, 63, 68, 72, 66, 89, 29, 10, 8, 7, 6, 15]
indices = [] #lista criada aqui

for j in range(len(posicao_1)):
    if posicao_1[j] in [24,18]:
        posicao_1[j] = aleatorio
        indices.append(j) #indice adicionado aqui, quando coloca aleatorios em posicao_1

for i in indices: #atribuição em posicao_2 com base nos indices
    posicao_2[i] = aleatorio
```

**Edit**

Para que a troca seja feita apenas pesquisando `[24,18]` como um sub-array já é necessário modificar um pouco a lógica que estava a ser feita.

```
...
#imports e posições para cima iguais 
pesq = [24,18]

#construir os indices verificando se a partir de cada posição o subarray existe no principal
indices = [x for x in range(len(posicao_1)) if posicao_1[x:x+len(pesq )] == pesq ]

#para cada indice substituir o subarray pela mesma quantidade de aleatorios
for i in indices:
    posicao_2[i: i+len(pesq)] = [aleatorio] * len(pesq)
```

Para pesquisar múltiplos tuplos basta transformar o array de pesquisa num array de tuplos e criar um outro `for`:

```
pesq = [[24,18], [62,63]]

for p in pesq:
    indices = [x for x in range(len(posicao_1)) if posicao_1[x:x+len(p)] == p ]

    for i in indices:
        posicao_2[i: i+len(p)] = [aleatorio] * len(p)
```

Comment: @Danilo Não sei se percebi a ideia. Apenas deve trocar quando são seguidos é isso? Se forem afastados já não é suposto trocar?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porém, acontece o seguinte: Se no meu vetor posicao_2 possuir algum outro valor [24] ou [18], é substituído também.

O que eu preciso é que seja substituído somente as posições onde estão [24, 18] e ignore caso existam outros valores [24] e [18] em outras posições.

desculpa incomodar. Mas, se você conseguir fazer isso, resolve todos os meus problemas.

Comment: Exatamente, @Isac

Comment: Preciso que seja trocada a posição da TUPLA (24, 18) e seja ignorado as outras posições onde aparecem [24] e [18].

Comment: conseguiu entender a ideia?

Comment: @Danilo Verifique se já obtem os resultados que espera

Comment: é exatamente essa lógica que eu preciso, porém caso minha "pesq"  seja por exemplo [24, 18, 62, 63] ele não consegue modificar.

Comment: Ou seja, caso eu precise modificar os índices no vetor posicao_2 onde estão os valores [24, 18] e [62, 63] ele não consegue.
Quando minha pesq tem somente 2 valores, o algoritmo funciona perfeitamente. Porém, quando pesq possui outras tuplas, ele não entende.

Comment: Desculpa estar te atrapalhando.

Comment: @Danilo A pesquisa é suposto ter só tuplos então, algo como `pesq = [[2,3], [34,21], etc..]` ? e acha os indices para quando tem correspondência nos dois valores de cada tuplo ?

Comment: Por exemplo, se pesq = [24, 18, 62, 63] o algoritmo precisa trocar os índices [2,3] e [ 5,6] do meu vetor posicao_2.

Falta bem pouco @Isac para acertarmos.

Comment: Exatamente @Isac.

Comment: Perfeito!!!!!!!!! Exatamente o que eu preciso.

Você está de parabéns. Muito, Muito Obrigado pela sua paciência e atenção.

Não somente nessa, mas em outras perguntas minhas.

Muito agradecido @Isac

Comment: como faço para atribuir uma tupla de valores diferentes, por exemplo, ao invés de atribuir [22, 22], atribua [22, 30]?

Comment: @Danilo Não percebi a pergunta, tem de ser um pouco mais especifico